# Length of a one line string

Tags: lengths

In the following TNWE (Tiny Not Working Example), I would like to align the braces on the right by calculating the lenghts of the texts such as to use `\kern` to fill spaces on right. Maybe blackmagic with boxes can do the job but this is far away from my tiny knowledge of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\test[2]{
    \{#1\}
    
    \{#2\}
}

\parindent=0em

\begin{document}

\test{Hello}{the world...}

\end{document}
```

I would like to obtain :

```
{Hello       }
{the world...}
```

The macro will be used in some environments where I can't do whatever I want. This why I would like to use `\kern`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No black magic, just standard features.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand{\dimmax}[2]{%
  \ifdim#1>#2 #1\else #2\fi
}
\newlength{\testupper}
\newlength{\testlower}
\newcommand\test[2]{%
  \par % ?
  \settowidth\testupper{#1}%
  \settowidth\testlower{#2}%
  \{\makebox[\dimmax{\testupper}{\testlower}][l]{#1}\}\par
  \{\makebox[\dimmax{\testupper}{\testlower}][l]{#2}\}\par
}

\setlength{parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\test{Hello}{the world\dots}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For me this looks like a little of sorcery for the moment. :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\test[2]{%%
\par
\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}l@{}l@{}}%
\{&#1&\}\\%
\{&#2&\}%
\end{tabular}\par}


\newcommand\testb[2]{%%
\par
\sbox0{#1}%
\sbox2{#2}%
\{#1\ifdim\wd2>\wd0 \kern\dimexpr\wd2-\wd0\relax\fi\}\par
\{#2\ifdim\wd0>\wd2 \kern\dimexpr\wd0-\wd2\relax\fi\}\par
}


\parindent=0em

\begin{document}

\test{Hello}{the world...}


\testb{Hello}{the world...}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This works but I can't use this solution as I mention it at the end of my post.

Comment: @projetmbc thought you might say that:-) I was adding a testb version but I don't like it as much:-) See update

Comment: Thanks a lot or this solution.

Comment: @projetmbc oh disaster! you've given the tick to that other bloke, he'll be so happy.

Comment: This is because his solution gives also the possibility to center the texts. He was lucky. That's all. :-)

Comment: @projetmbc but he didn't do what you asked and use a kern:-) (you could centre these by using `c` in the first or using a kern of `0.5\dimexpr...`  before and after `#1` and `#2` in the testb case

Comment: Unfair tick has been deleted. You're right.

Comment: actually I didn't mean you had to move the tick but I'm sure egreg will be even happier to see it awarded to a more deserving post.